# Admin - Customers - Manage Customers - Edit - Goes To Blank Page

Tags: magento-1.9

When I am in Admin and go to Customers and then to Manage Customers it produces a list of the customers, but if I try and edit any of them, either by clicking on the customer or clicking on Edit next to a customer it just takes me to a blank page.

I've looked at every answer I could find and tried the solution, but nothing fixes it.

I edited my public_html/php.ini file and increased the `memory_limit from 128m to 512m`. I edited my .htaccess file and added this line: `suPHP_ConfigPath /home/CUSTOMERID/public_html (changing the CUSTOMERID, to my Hosting CustomerId`.

I `tried` a suggestion went into

**app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/grid.php and changed:**

```
public function getRowUrl($item)
{
    $res = parent::getRowUrl($item);
    return ($res ? $res : '#');
}

}
```

to

```
public function getRowUrl($item) 
{ 
return $this->getUrl(’*/*/edit’, array(’id’ => $item->getId())); 
}
```

Which **totally crashed my ADMIN until I reinstalled the original Grid.php file**.

I looked in index.php file for this line to see about error reporting: `ini_set('display_errors',1);`

and found that this was already in:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I looked in `error_log and didn't find any errors concerning Admin`.

Answer (score 1):

This means your `customer.xml` file is edited and it had some bad codes inside it. Errors like this can be easily traced out, if you put your site in development mode. For this ***[you need to try this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store/429#429)*** .

In short, you need to edit `index.php` in your root directory and

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

do the above mentioned changes. You also need to activate log files via admin side. For this go to `System > Configuration > Developer > log`.

This way you will get an idea on what actually gone wrong in `customer.xml` file. Hope that will help you in future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just as I was posting this and looking back at all of the solutions I tried I came across someone mentioning that they reinstalled the customer.xml file in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/

So I reinstalled the customer.hml file from the original Magento files, and boom, that fixed it. Don't know what was wrong or why, or if I screwed anything else up, but it's working right now.